# phpmyadmin is not accessable

Tags: apache2, lamp, phpmyadmin

I have installed and configured lamp stack from the steps described at digitalOcean. everything is perfect. I have set up multiple host. but I cant access the phpmyadmin. its giving not found error..

**

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.
> Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

**

note that I have a host setup using **localhost** alias.
what have I missed can someone assist?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What EXACT command did you use that gives this error?

Comment: Just to confirm, the LAMP stack was installed on *your local computer* and not a different machine, correct? If so, can you [edit] your question to include: (1) the Apache config file for the site (in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`) (2) the output of `ls -AlF /var/www`. With this it will be easier to offer a specific solution 

Comment: I have included site conf file in the given directory. 
I am using ubuntu 20.05 lts
and didn't used any command that gave me the error. I simply tried to access phpmyadmin by localhost/phpmyadmin.. and the error is on the browser page